# How to filter a table by unique column and organize them by group in separate column in SQL (complex request)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table and I would like to filter (and group) it by country and add column for each age like this

Table :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnfCe.jpg)

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocoSn.jpg)

Is it possible ? I tried with
`SELECT DISTINCT country FROM myTable`
to avoid the redundancy for country

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Comment: If you actually need columns, this will be a pivot. But is it possible you just want a list and could use `listagg` or `string_agg` instead of columns?

Comment: It's with PostgreSQL, I'm trying some request with this online compiler https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/

Comment: Yes, thank you, I tried withe the PIVOT but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with crosstab(). [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zNblyCO3)

Crosstab requires three columns (row name, category, and value) so I added a category column based on the country.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (age INT, country varchar(2), cat int);
INSERT INTO temp
VALUES
(22,'US',1),
(21,'US',1),
(35,'UK',2),
(32,'UK',2),
(44,'UK',2),
(19,'IT',3),
(25,'ES',4),
(19,'FR',5),
(51,'UK',2),
(26,'ES',4);
```

I then pivoted the data with crosstab.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM crosstab('select country, cat, age from temp order by cat asc'
               ) AS temp(country varchar(2), age1 int, age2 int, age3 int, age4 int);
```

Which returns

| country | age1 | age2 | age3 | age4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 21 | 22 | null | null |
| UK | 51 | 35 | 32 | 44 |
| IT | 19 | null | null | null |
| FR | 19 | null | null | null |
| ES | 25 | 26 | null | null |